# Pass string from html inside <object> into Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables

I have a flash movie that is being used for several websites. On each site I would like to specify a different XML file inside the markup.  How do I grab that string and use it in ActionScript?

in markup i want to do this:

```
<object ...
   <param name=FlashVars value="urlXML=myXML.xml" />
</object>
```

in actionscript 3.0, im trying to do this:

```
var urlXML=_root.urlXML;
```

Currently when I do this, I get an error in output saying 'access of undefined property...'  How am i supposed to grab that string?

Comment: This is a fairly common mistake when people move to AS3. You should update the question with the answer or write your own answer, so other people finding this entry can find it more easily.
Or posible making it a wiki.

Comment: Forgot to mention swfobject. You should look at it for embedding you flash object.
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how you access FlashVars in AS3. You need the root loaderInfo's parameter property, that houses any FlashVars that were tacked on.

```
var urlXML: String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.urlXML;
```

Comment: this worked for me too:
var urlXML = loaderInfo.parameters.urlXML;

Answer (score 0):

Note: Adobe KB  [article](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_16417)

> FlashVars must be assigned in both the OBJECT and EMBED tags in order to work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

My first response... so here goes:

I have a small video player application I developed for McGill University Alumni.
You can see it here:
http://www.alumni.mcgill.ca/esol/holiday/2008/flash.php?giftCode=123456
It picks up a 'Gift Code' from the URL but you can always hard-code your .xml file.

Here are the object and embed (s) I use:

```
<embed src="mcgill_annual_fund200903.swf**?giftCode=<?php echo $giftCode; ?>**" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="680" height="550"></embed>
```

And with the .js embed script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','680','height','550','src','mcgill_annual_fund200903**?giftCode=**','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','mcgill_annual_fund200903?giftCode=','wmode','transparent' ); //end AC code

And then to retrieve the info in AS3:

```
//get the giftCode
var gCode:String;
var giftCode:String;
function loaderComplete(lEvent:Event){
    gCode = loaderInfo.loaderURL;
    giftCode = gCode.substr((gCode.indexOf("?giftCode=")+10));
    //giftCodeTxt.text= giftCode;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should just be there--you don't need the _root.  See [this](http://blog.circlecube.com/2008/05/22/flashvar-tutorial/).

Comment: That was in AS2.  But I found the solution. I needed this line of code:

var urlXML = loaderInfo.parameters.urlXML;